# Unable to cast HTMLSelectElement in typescript

Tags: html, typescript, angular5

I am using angular 5. In .ts file when i try to typecast my element to HTMLSelectElement it throws some error. I checked the documentation but the value option is available in HTMLSelectElement. I don't know what i'm doing wrong;

.ts file:

inside get_department function:

```
var selected_box = <HTMLSelectElement(document.getElementById('departments')).value;
```

HTML FILE:

```
<select id="departments" class="form-control" (change)="get_department();">
    <option value="">Select</option>
    <option value="prm">PRM</option>
    <option value = "crm">CRM</option>
    <option value = "crdx">CRDX</option>
  </select>
```

Error:

> Property 'value' does not exist on type 'HTMLElement'.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should put the assertion inside the parenthesis:

```
var selected_box = (<HTMLSelectElement>document.getElementById('departments')).value;
// OR
var selected_box = (document.getElementById('departments') as HTMLSelectElement).value;
```

Answer (score 3):

You just do this.

```
 <select class="form-control" (change)="get_department($event);">
        <option>Select</option>
        <option> PRM </option>
        <option> CRM </option>
        <option> CRDX </option>
      </select>
```

> In .ts

```
get_department(event){ var selected_box = event.target.vlue;  }
```

Answer (score 1):

> HTML

```
<select id="departments" class="form-control" (change)="get_department($event)">
  <option value="">Select</option>
  <option value="prm">PRM</option>
  <option value="crm">CRM</option>
  <option value="crdx">CRDX</option>
</select>
```

> TS

```
// Type assertion happens here
get_department(event: HTMLSelectElement) {
  var selected_box = event.target.value;

  console.log(selected_box);
}
```

> **You should not access the document directly**

like `document.getElementById('departments').value`.

1. It prevents deployment of the project using Angular Universal
2. which in turn makes SEO optimization for the project impossible
3. Plus all the other benefit of Angular Universal is lost